# Is it possible to declare a trait that accepts more methods that the ones declared in its body?

Tags: rust, traits

Something like:

```rust
pub trait MyTrait {
    // No methods defined/declared
}

impl MyTrait for MyType {
    fn method_one_not_declared_neither_defined(&self) {
        // body of trait method impl here
    }

    fn method_two_not_declared_neither_defined(&self) {
        // body of trait method impl here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the trait itself cannot be extended, you *can* still add behaviour to all types which implement a trait. This can be done using [extension traits](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0445-extension-trait-conventions.html) and blanket implementations.

```rust
trait MyTrait {}

struct MyType;

impl MyTrait for MyType {}

trait TraitExt {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Foo");
    }
}

impl<T> TraitExt for T where T: MyTrait {}

fn main() {
    let t = MyType {};
    t.foo();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4247143ed17dde397b05aa7647c1cac7)

This is not the same as extending `MyTrait` however - `TraitExt` must be in scope for `foo` to be called.

Comment: In the real code, does not solves my problem, but responds exactly to the question answered, and is an interesting one that I didn't know about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. Only methods declared in trait definition might be implemented when implementing trait for a type. You can add this methods as normal type's methods, but not as trait's. Think of a trait as a public interface. You *must* implement all of trait's methods (besides those with default implementation) and *cannot* add anything more.